# Extracting dates from text Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a column of texts from a column called 'internal notes' from a CRM and i am trying to using pandas to extract the dates into an new column as an array.
Everything is loaded, I'd love to give some coding examples I've tried but everything I've attempted is nowhere near.

An couple of examples are:

1.

```
14/05/21 - Called in and saw owner and left wholesale list with her. 
Owner was in NZ though returning this weekend.
Follow up 21/05/21
```

2.

```
26/02/07 Hold feb 07 till contacted (around mid March) - was missed in the send out as was originally entered as 
"Oth-White" had sufficient funds at beginning of Feb but has used the money OK
28/03/2007 emailed for update - purchase etc
13/4/07 - did not cancel due to mix up above - contact for Aug 07 - if no response cancel then JP
8/8/08 - NO AUG 08 BUT KEEN TO STAY A MEMBER
01/02/09 - REQUESTED NO FEB 09
01/02/10 REQUESTED NO FEB 10
01/08/09 REQUESTED NO AUG 09 - OK
18/12/09 - Changed to Email
01/08/2010 NO AUG 10 REQUESTED      
Cancelled as per members request 15/02/2011
```

The output i need would be

1. {'14/05/21', '21/05/21'}
2. {'26/02/07', '28/03/07', '08/08/08', '01/02/09', '01/02/10', '01/08/09', '18/12/09', '01/08/10'}

Any questions or any other info needed please let me know.

Comment: I would be ideal to provide your input as dataframe (this is currently ambiguous), and als provide the output that you expect

Comment: Sure the input is:
data_frame = data[['ID*','User Group', 'zMembership Status', 'zCategory', 'Internal Notes']]

Comment: you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70967296/edit) your question ;)

Comment: sorry mozway you are right forgot the desired output, is there anything else you would suggest?

Comment: a dataframe input would have been more explicit, but thanks! I provided one in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70967840/edit), if this is not what you have please update the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex to find the day, month, year.

In this case one expects to have a combination of `day/month/year` in every string. Otherwise you have to implement a `try` and `except` statement.

Here I will show one example. You can easily write this to a function and apply it to each row in your DataFrame, but I do not have your DataFrame and I think that it is sufficient to show the method how it works, so you can convert it to a function yourself.

```
import re
import datetime

s = "26/02/07 Hold feb 07 till contacted (around mid March) - was missed in the send out as was originally entered as"
dates = re.search(r'(?P<day>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<year>\d+)', s).groupdict()
# This will create a dictionary:
# {'day': '26', 'month': '02', 'year': '07'}
#Then you can for example check the year, because it can be "07" or "2007":
if len(dates['year']) < 4:
    dates['year'] = '20'+ dates['year']
dt = datetime.datetime(year=int(dates['year']), month=int(dates['month']), day=int(dates['day']))

# OR:
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('-'.join(dates.values()), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

What happens here is that regex will return a named dictionary. After that you can check you year format and use that as input for a `datetime` object.

Comment: +1, regex is the way to go. If OP really has his data (the blocks of text) stored in a dataframe (`df`), he could use [`df.str_col.str.extract(regex_pattern)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) to apply the regex to each row in the column and extract the matches.

Comment: Nice addition, I was not aware of that function. In this case I am not sure of it is easier that way since you also want to check for the year format, but I definitely can think of different use cases (even this one with some tweaking) or with large dataframes that this is very handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The input you have is still ambiguous so let's assume this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'internal notes': ['14/05/21 - Called in and saw owner and left wholesale list with her. \nOwner was in NZ though returning this weekend.\nFollow up 21/05/21\n',
                                      '26/02/07 Hold feb 07 till contacted (around mid March) - was missed in the send out as was originally entered as \n"Oth-White" had sufficient funds at beginning of Feb but has used the money OK\n28/03/2007 emailed for update - purchase etc\n13/4/07 - did not cancel due to mix up above - contact for Aug 07 - if no response cancel then JP\n8/8/08 - NO AUG 08 BUT KEEN TO STAY A MEMBER\n01/02/09 - REQUESTED NO FEB 09\n01/02/10 REQUESTED NO FEB 10\n01/08/09 REQUESTED NO AUG 09 - OK\n18/12/09 - Changed to Email\n01/08/2010 NO AUG 10 REQUESTED      \nCancelled as per members request 15/02/2011\n',
                                     ]})

#                                       internal notes
# 0  14/05/21 - Called in and saw owner and left wh...
# 1  26/02/07 Hold feb 07 till contacted (around mi...
```

You can use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract the dates using the `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}` regex, then combined all the matches with [`groupby`+`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and aggregate to python [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to have unique elements.

```
(df['internal notes']
 .str.extractall('(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})')[0]
 .rename('New_col')
 .groupby(level=0).apply(set)
)
```

output:

```
0                                 {14/05/21, 21/05/21}
1    {18/12/09, 26/02/07, 15/02/20, 01/08/09, 01/08...
Name: New_col, dtype: object
```

regex (this is a simple one and would also match incorrect dates such as 99/99/99):

```
\d{2}   # two digits
/       # a literal /
\d{2}   # two digits
/       # a literal /
\d{2}   # two digits
```